# What kind of encryption is this?

Tags: objective-c, encryption

I am using an open-source encryption library in my iOS app, in the description it states that it is AES 256-bit encryption. Does this mean that ONLY the key size is AES 256-bit?

What puzzles me is that the Key Size is 256, but the algorithm and block size are 128. So which type of encryption is the library using and why are they different?

```
#define FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM     kCCAlgorithmAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE    kCCBlockSizeAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE      kCCKeySizeAES256
```

Comment: 4 answers in a minute from people that have > 3K experience, must be a record for the encryption tag :)

Comment: @owlstead And answers in agreement, no less.  Shall we upvote one another? :-)

Comment: woah. thanks for all the answers! Sorry I can only pick one tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These constants are declared in [CommonCryptor.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h), which includes helpful comments.

AES is a block cipher that uses 128 bit blocks irrespective of key size.  Consequently, `kCCAlgorithmAES128` is just "longhand" for AES generally.

So, the code indicates that it's using standard AES with a 256 bit encryption key.

Answer (score 3):

This is how AES works - the block size is 128 regardless of the key size.  This does not mean that it only uses 128 bits of the key.  Full info in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aes256).

Answer (score 3):

AES only supports block sizes of 128 bits. Rijndael, which it is based on does support different block sizes though. There is some difference between AES-128, 192 and 256 (the subkey derivation may be specific to the key size and the number of rounds is different), but the underlying algorithm is the same, and always uses 128 bit (16 byte) blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The AES Standard ([FIPS-197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)) (not the just the Rijndael algorithm) states:

> This standard specifies the **Rijndael** algorithm ([3] and [4]), a symmetric block cipher that can 
>   process  **data blocks** of  **128 bits**, using cipher **keys**  with lengths of  **128**,  **192**, and  **256** bits. 
>   Rijndael was designed to handle additional block sizes and key lengths, however they are not 
>   adopted in this standard.